# display no internet error in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hello again I'm trying to get an error to display in the app below if there is no internet connection. Here are the files.
FirstViewController.h:

```
//
//  FirstViewController.h
//  DailyJoke
//
//  Created by John Bridge on 5/4/11.
//  Copyright 2011 Bridge and co. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
}
@end
```

Here is FirstViewController.m:
    //
    //  FirstViewController.m
    //  DailyJoke
    //
    //  Created by John Bridge on 5/4/11.
    //  Copyright 2011 Bridge and co. All rights reserved.
    //

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"


@implementation FirstViewController




-(void)awakeFromNib
{
        [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL             URLWithString:@"http://www.johnbridge180.com/IPhoneIPad/IPhone/DailyJoke/DailyJoke.html"]]];
}

/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the     view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/

/*
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a     nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
*/

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement UIWebViewDelegate to your controller class. And override following methods in your controller class. These methods names are self explanatory. You need to handle errors accordingly. Set your webview delegate to your controller class by setting following sentence in your viewDidLoad method.Also dont forget to implement UIWebViewDelegate to your class.

> - webView.delegate = self;

```
#pragma mark webView delegate
-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)wView{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = TRUE;
}
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{
    if ([error code] == -999) {
    }   
    else if([error code] == -1009 || [[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"no Internet connection"]){
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;
    }
    else if([error code] == -1001 || [[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"timed out"]){      
    }
    else if([error code] == -1004 || [[error localizedDescription] isEqualToString:@"can’t connect to host"]){              
    }
    else if (error != NULL) {       
    }
    else{       
    }
}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)wView{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = FALSE;  
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It's always better to use the enums provided by Apple instead of entering the codes hardcoded. Like this one: NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet.
See here for the no-internet code:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrornotconnectedtointernet?language=objc

Comment: @YonatanGoriachnick You are welcome to update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of folks use the Reachability example provided by apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Looks like:
+ (Reachability*) reachabilityWithHostName: (NSString*) hostName;
would be the place start.

Another way would be to load the HTML using an NSURLConnection and supply it to the webview.  If the url connection fails, the client probably doesn't have an internet connection.

Comment: I'm still confused srry im new

Comment: You should take time to try the sample code or read more documentation before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
```

You can find network error codes here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes